# Return after $.ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies

I've this piece of code, and i built the other function only to try another way to do that.

```
var cookie_val = "";
    function getCookie() {        
        $.when($.ajax("../handlers/users/get_user.ashx")).then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $.when(getCookieValue(data)).then(function () {
                cookie_val = $.cookie("default_value:" + cookie_val);
            });            
        });
        return cookie_val;
    }
    function getCookieValue(data) {
        cookie_val = data;
    }
```

this works, but only if i execute the function twice, how can i do to make this work at the first call?

Comment: you need to read the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the `ajax` request to finish before grabbing the value: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ .  The requests made in `getCookie` are both asynchronous, so they don't halt other code from executing while they are waiting for a response from the server.  There's two ways you can get around this:

Return the deferred object created in `getCookie`

```
function getCookie() {
    return $.when(....
}
```

And when it's done, do what you need with the cookie value

```
getCookie().done(function (cookie_value) {
    console.log(cookie_value);
});
```

Alternatively, make the call synchronous: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
function getCookie() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../hnadlers/users/get_user.ashx', 
        async: false
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        cookie_value = $.cookie('default_value:' + data);
    });
    return getCookieValue();
}
```

Also, are you sure `getCookieValue` shouldn't return `cookie_val`, as your current implementation suggests, it should be named `setCookieValue`.

Comment: _"Alternatively, make the call synchronous"_ Making the call synchronous should never be considered when there is an alternative. And when it seems like there isn't an alternative, look again because there probably is.